# Is there a way to delete creeps?

Tags: javascript, screeps

Is it possible to delete created creeps? Either through a script or through the GUI?

I could not easily find a way to do this, but it seems like a simple functionality so I imagine it exists, or someone has thought about it or something.

Comment: Please tell me why I got -1, don't just leave a negative thing and not explain.

Comment: I don't see why you would want to delete one, but I do think it is a valid question.

Comment: Just to clarify, I upvoted this question.

Comment: Thanks, and don't worry, I figured that :)

Comment: Oh, and my reason for deleting a creep would just be to keep things neat, like if I make a creep I didn't really want and now he's just there for a while, breaking the perfectness. It's possible that *you* wouldn't want to delete one, but there's definitely reasons *one* might, like me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Creep.suicide`](http://screeps.com/docs/Creep.php#suicide) method.

```
for(var i in Game.creeps) {
    Game.creeps[i].suicide(); // lemmings style!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set the creep = null

```
Game.creeps.Harvester1 = null
```

this deletes it and removes all its energy.

Comment: Not remove, but drop it's energy too.
Also: `creep.suicide();`